# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) -> Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm taking a course of Laravel, and I'm with some problems during the Databases Module...

It's about "php artisan migrate", when I try to do this command, appears me this message: [After do the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lolhU.png)

That's my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

(I've already try put password at .env, but still the same)

Comment: if you password contain special character then add it in quote.DB_PASSWORD='3sd#$@'.Also verify mysql running in same port.all correct then run php artisan config:clear

Comment: Still the same. I think it's because i'm using root, in other foruns, they said to change the root, but I try and still nothing.

Comment: update datase.php file in question.again try to login in mysql with same username and password.

Comment: Did you rebuild cache after modifying .env ? php artisan config:cache

Comment: I've updated, but nothing happens, I can login in mysql with the same user (root) and password (but just using sudo as well)...

Comment: Config no @Suleman, I always rebuild or reset cache after a modify

Comment: After I reconfig the cache (like @Suleman said), appears another error, but i think now i'll works fine

Comment: I am having the same problem all of a sudden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(@Suleman and @John Lobo, can you make an answer so that I can rate it as correct?!)

It's just `php artisan config:cache` after some changes at .env and database.php (like @John Lobo said)

Comment: I'd suggest just deleting your negatively-scored question; it's a common mistake and this answer is unlikely to help future users.

Comment: Slack itself doesn't let you delete, an "error" appears saying that people invested their time in the question, so I can't delete it

Comment: You’d have to uncheck your answer first.

Comment: I've tried that too, still the same message

Answer (score -1):

The error message is telling you the issue - that the user 'root' doesn't have access to the database without a password being specified.

Do you know your root password?
Has one been set?

If you know your password add it to your .env file.
If one hasn't been set read the manual for mysql/mariadb on your operating system for how to set the root password - then add it to the .env file.

Comment: I've already try put a password at .env, the same password that I use at mysql, but still the same...